# Proving substitution rule of taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Given $f, g$ which are both nth differential-able. How do I show that $f(g)$ is also nth differentai-able ? I tried using chain rule to calculate, but it seems like a mess.

Then how can I show that the taylor polynomial of order $n$ at $0$ is just $T(S(x))$ truncated all terms having power greater than $n$, where T is the taylor series for $f$ and $S$ is for $g.$ I tried using the fact that $(f-T)/x^n\rightarrow 0$ and $(g-S)/x^n\rightarrow 0.$ Any help will be appreciated. Thanks